# Como fazer deploy de aplicações Laravel 4.2 via FTP?

Tags: laravel, deploy, ftp

Olá,

Estou querendo fazer deploy de uma aplicação em Laravel 4.2 via FTP, porém os recursos e tutoriais que encontrei não conseguiram sanar o problema. Alguem poderia me indicar um método?

Comment: Suba todas os arquivos do seu projeto, incluindo a pasta vendor, simples.

Comment: hã? Subir pasta vendors? está brincando né? sobe apenas aplicação, e de um composer install via ssh, assimele gera o autoload bonitinho, se não dará erro

Answer (score 1):

Para ferramenta de deploy utilize o http://dploy.io/ ele funciona de várias formas, e uma das é FTP, e isso vai lhe atender, você terá que ter um repositório no bit ou no git seguindo as regras do seu servidor. O que o Daniel disse sobre a pastas public e arquivos tem que estar configurado nesse repositório. Teste a ferramenta, eu testei por FTP apenas por titulo de curiosidade, mas atualmente eu utilizo o forge

Answer (score 0):

Na pasta public do servidor(que geralmente é public_html) joga os arquivos que estão na pasta public local o resto dos arquivos tudo abaixo dela, ai manda todos os arquivos, inclusive a pasta vendor.
Depois muda o arquivo bootstrap/paths.php e pronto.
Só atenção que requer php 5.4